# VBA Lastrow to not include certain values

Tags: excel, vba

I made this macro (and it works!) but I want to expand on it. Some of the data in the "Data" sheet is irrelevant and I don't want to autofill those rows in the "Databehandling" sheet.

I want to change the LastRow definition. Column G in my data-sheet contains a lot of dates and times (ex. 2016-09-26 09:42:56.290) and the data connected with the last date (2016-09-26) messes with my analysis (a lot of null-values because there's no data as-of-yet). Since I have to update this workbook regularly, I can't just say exclude 2016-09-26. The macro has to look at the date at the very bottom of the data-sheet and move the selection up so those dates aren't included in the selection.

So how can I do that?

```
Sub Kviklevering_Drag_Down()

On Error GoTo errHandler
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ActiveWorkbook
    Lastrow = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data").UsedRange.Rows.Count

    Sheets("Databehandling").Activate

    Range("A2:V2").Select

    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:V" & Lastrow), Type:=xlFillDefault
    End With

Sheets("Databehandling").Visible = False
Sheets("Data").Activate

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

errHandler:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Try adding -1 to where you set the Lastrow:  Lastrow = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data").UsedRange.Rows.Count -1

Comment: If each date only appears once then use the -1 that @Thomas said, otherwise use a COUNTIF to get how often the last date appears and remove that from your last row - providing the dates are in order.

Comment: I wouldn't use USEDRANGE either - that can give incorrect results.  Use something like `.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` (for column A).

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook So that would look something like: Lastrow = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row instead of having the UsedRange. The difficult part is doing the whole countif part. The values in column G are: yyyy:dd:mm hh:mm:sssss. But I only want to count a value if the date matches - not the time.

Comment: To get last row (as @DarrenBartrup-Cook mentioned), declare a worksheet variable: `Dim oWS As Worksheet: Set oWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")`. Now you can use this to get last row: `Lastrow = oWS.Cells(oWS.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`. Note that `1` refers to column `A`, 2 will refer to column `B` and so on

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your code.  Removed looking at the ActiveBook, activating sheets and moved the error handler outside the main procedure (after the `Exit Sub`, but before the `End Sub`).

```
Sub Kviklevering_Drag_Down()

    Dim CountOfMaxDate As Long
    Dim rLastCell As Range
    Dim rCountRange As Range
    Dim dMaxDate As Double


    'Are you sure it's always the ActiveWorkbook?
    'May be better to use ThisWorkbook which is always the file with this code in,
    'or a specific named workbook.
    'With ActiveWorkbook
   On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    With ThisWorkbook

        With Worksheets("Data")
            'Find last cell in column G (column 7).
            Set rLastCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp)
            If rLastCell.Row = 1 Then
                Err.Raise vbObjectError + 1000, , "Last Cell is row 1"
            End If
            Set rCountRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 7), rLastCell)
            'Get the value of the last date.
            dMaxDate = Int(rLastCell)

            'Count the last date.
            CountOfMaxDate = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(rCountRange, ">=" & dMaxDate, rCountRange, "<" & dMaxDate + 1)
        End With

        'No need to active this sheet - can leave it hidden if you want.
        With Worksheets("Databehandling")
            .Range("A2:V2").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("A2:V" & rLastCell.Row - CountOfMaxDate), Type:=xlFillDefault
        End With

    End With

FastExit:
    'Tidy up before exiting procedure.

Exit Sub

   On Error GoTo 0
   Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:

    Select Case Err.Number
        Case -2147220504 'Last Cell is row 1
            'Handle error.

            'Possible things to do after error handled:
            'Resume Next
            'Resume
            'Resume FastExit
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure Kviklevering_Drag_Down."
    End Select

End Sub
```